# How would one parse such data?

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing, html-parsing, helper

I have some data format that I want to parse, what type is this? I feel that this is not the typical array.

http://aavirtual.net/src/vatsim-data.txt

Is the link to the data file. I have tried a split command but then the top part all comes in. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How is this related to Parse.com platform ?